# Python 3 error: 'module' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split

In the Python 2.7 interpreter, the string split function works as expected:

```
>>> import string
>>> a = "a b c"
>>> string.split(a)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But, in the Python 3.4.1 interpreter, I get an error:

```
>>> import string
>>> a = "a b c"
>>> string.split(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: No need to import String just call `split` on the string: `a.split()`

Comment: Didn't you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)? The `string.split` function is documented under the heading [***Deprecated*** string functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions). This is what happens when something is deprecated: it will disappear in future versions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call it as well over the class str:

```
str.split("a b c")     

['a', 'b', 'c']
```